# ITelephony.endCall() doesn't work anymore for blocking calls in Android 8/Android O/API 26

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app that uses the following code to block calls:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = 
    (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

try {
    Class<?> telephonyManagerClass = 
        Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
    Method getITelephonyMethod = 
        telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
    Object iTelephony = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
    Class<?> iTelephonyClass = Class.forName(iTelephony.getClass().getName());
    Method endCallMethod = iTelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
    endCallMethod.setAccessible(true);
    endCallMethod.invoke(iTelephony);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // ClassNotFoundException
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // NoSuchMethodException
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // IllegalAccessException
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // InvocationTargetException
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Some other exception
}
```

To work, this required android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE in AndroidManifest.xml. In Android M and N, I also had to ask the user for permission Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE.

But now in Android 8/Android O, the above code fails with InvocationTargetException: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required

I found this related StackOverflow post: [Android - Why does endCall method work but answerRingingCall doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584372/android-why-does-endcall-method-work-but-answerringingcall-doesnt-work)

Here it is suggested that I might be able to use reflection on PhoneInterfaceManager (instead of ITelephony, like I have done above) and use the private method sendRequestAsync(int command) with the end call command, and by doing this getting around the security measure inside the endCall() method.

Has anyone tried something like this? Is it possible? How would I even get the PhoneInterfaceManager object/class instead of ITelephony?

I think this is the source code in question: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telephony/+/oreo-release/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java

I can't see any difference between this and the code for Android N when it comes to ending calls, so I might be mistaken:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telephony/+/nougat-release/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java

Comment: Note that none of this stuff may work on Android P, as [they are implementing bans on such reflection](https://developer.android.com/preview/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).

Comment: It doesn't help with Android 8.x but FYI Android P Beta 2 has exposed the endCall method in TelecomManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#endCall()). I just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads up! Not an answer to my question, but very useful information in getting the app to keep working in the future.

Comment: Did you found any way to end call on Oreo ? @BjarteAuneOlsen

Comment: @KishorV: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Nikola Brežnjak's blog, I found an answer: https://dev.to/hitman666/how-to-make-a-native-android-app-that-can-block-phone-calls--4e15

Basically, you need to include the ITelephony interface in your project. Create a file ITelephony.class with the following code (keep the namespace):

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

public interface ITelephony {
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
}
```

Then from your code, use the following code to end a phone call:

```
// This is only useful on Android O and older
// Needs permission CALL_PHONE
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O
    || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    return;
}

try {
    ITelephony telephonyService;

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    Method getITelephony = telephonyManager
            .getClass()
            .getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

    getITelephony.setAccessible(true);

    telephonyService = (ITelephony) getITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

    telephonyService.endCall();

} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

Comment: Android Pie has built in solution to end call, so you don't have to use reflection: TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE); telecomManager.endCall();

Comment: But what about 8.0.1, you cannot use reflection on O, new solution is available on P ?

Comment: I'm doing this on Lollipop and the method exists here. I have the supposedly correct permissions and I'm running the app as a system app and with root permissions. But this freezes the entire app. I can answer or end the call, but then the app freezes. Would you know a reason?

Comment: @Pankaj: The method described above (with reflection) should work on Android 8.1 (Oreo) and below. I think I have tried it down to Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), if I remember correctly.

Comment: @DADi590: I'm not sure why it freezes, but as you can see by all the try-catches in my original question, there are lots of things that can fail when using reflection :-)

Comment: I have Exception instead of all those. No exception appears. Nothing at all. No idea why. So I've put everything in a service, I start the service, wait 0.5 seconds and I kill it - it's on a separate process, so I kill the PID. Only way I found out to go around that. It still freezes. I found another method (with more things and using reflection but without the class you have there) that doesn't let endCall freeze, but answerRingingCall still freezes. This is weird.