Call block on Android Studio (Kotlin 2024)
I am creating a anti Telefony Denial of Service app for... do not ask why !
Is the phone receive 3 calls under a minute then there is a suspection of attack so I want to block instantanely the incoming calls on the device. But my code is not working (of course or I wouldn't be a good programmer right ?).
All jokes aside, I already ask for every persmission about phone state.
Please help me implement this feature (it is the main goal) :
// Check for high call volume and notify user
                if (callTimestamps.size > 2) {
                    "High call volume detected".logEvent(context)
                    notifyUser(context)

                    // Block the call if call blocking is enabled
                    if (isCallBlockingEnabled && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        val telecomManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as? TelecomManager
                        if (telecomManager != null && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            telecomManager.endCall()
                        }
                    }
                }

Here is the permissions I ask for :
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

Thanks in advance !!!
What I expected :
On virtual AND physical phone (no API version problem in the logcat) :
I inject 3 call towards the victims within 30 seconds, I get the notification about the potential attack (which means my condition is fulfilled) but I continue to receive calls after that....
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION : i don't know if this is important since I quite new with Kotlin but I set up a "disable call blocking" function in the notification

may it be that this helps?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760074/itelephony-endcall-doesnt-work-anymore-for-blocking-calls-in-android-8-androi

thanks you I will test this but I expect this to work

I finally tested the solution I linked anddd... it did not work for me, I just tested this code on 2 different devices and it seems to work:
private fun cutTheCall(context: Context) {
    val telecomManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as? TelecomManager
    val readPhoneStatePermissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    val answerPhoneCallsPermissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        context,
        Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    if (readPhoneStatePermissionGranted && answerPhoneCallsPermissionGranted && telecomManager != null
    ) {
        if (telecomManager.isInCall) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                telecomManager.endCall()
            }
        }
    }

if the following permissions are granted (and added to manifest)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

but it shows a deprication warning about .endCall() for API > 29, that you can fix by implementing call screening service, but it seems to require more from the user

I tried and it worked on my virtual device but not on my physical one. however thank you this is very helpful I will also try to activate the Do Not Disturb mode instead
